# can't insert in mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to make a registration form. I can connect successfully to mySQL database but i can't insert anything to my table named "hackers" from my html form. Here is my form and my php script.

I also tried to insert data manually in $sql to see if the problem is in the form, but $sql doesn't add data either.

Your help is much much appreciated!!!!!!!

```
<?php
include"config.php";

$insert = 'INSERT INTO hackers (name,email, school, grad-year)  VALUES('$_POST['name']','$_POST['email']','$_POST['school']','$_POST['gradYear']')';


$sql= 'INSERT INTO mydatabase_name.hackers (name,email, school, grad-year) VALUES ('text', 'text', 'text', 'text')';

mysql_query($insert);
mysql_query($sql);


?>
```

My form:

```
<form method = "post" action ="process.php" >
    <table id ="registration_form">
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><input type= "text" name="name"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>email</td>
        <td><input type= "text" name="email"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>school</td>
        <td><input type= "text" name="school"/></td>
    </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>graduation year</td>
        <td><input type= "text" name="gradYear"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type= "submit" name="submit" value ="Submit"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If no, make sure you have `display_errors = on` in your php.ini file. Or you can set it by ` ini_set("display_errors", 1);` just after the config's include. If there's an error, you'll see it. Please post it here for further investigation.

Comment: these are the errors that i get . Thank you so much !!                                                         Connected successfully

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home4/malonzoc/public_html/hackholyoke/test/process.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'vjanardhan'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home4/malonzoc/public_html/hackholyoke/test/process.php on line 17

Comment: `grad-year` MySQL is interpreting that as "grad MINUS year". I can't see how anyone missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate with `.`, use double quotes on the outside and single values for value adding. For example:

```
"INSERT INTO hackers (name,email, school, grad-year)  VALUES('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['school']."','".$_POST['gradYear']."')"
```

Although I want to note that this isn't a good idea as you are prone to SQL-injections. You want to escape or prepare the query first before you execute it.

For your manually entered string you have a similar problem. In this case an easy fix is to have double quotes on the outside of the string and single quotes on the inside, the problem is that this `ES ('te` closes the string for the query here: `$sql= 'INS`.

```
"INSERT INTO mydatabase_name.hackers (name,email, school, grad-year) VALUES ('text', 'text', 'text', 'text')"
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggestion and it still didn't work. I am commecting through phpMyadmin. Do you think there is a configuration i'm missing?

Comment: @Nach Alright, see if my edit works. When adding values you need to have it like so: `VALUES('someValue')`, with single quotes. The example I gave didn't have them as they where being used for the string itself.

Comment: @Nach Also Pankaj example would work, and it's the way I would recommenced doing it as it's cleaner in the query (you would want to escape the items through when you define them).

Comment: I get these errors .  Connected successfully Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home4/malonzoc/public_html/hackholyoke/test/process.php on line 16 Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'vjanardhan'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home4/malonzoc/public_html/hackholyoke/test/process.php on line 17

Comment: <?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "mydbusername";
$dbpassword = "my pass";
$dbname ="mydb_name";

// Create connection
$connect = mysql_connect($localhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect);

// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed again: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
    
?>

Comment: this is how i connect to my database.

Comment: @Nach Change the user to *"root"* other than *"vjanardhan"*, which is default. It appears the user with that username does not have permission to access the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$school= $_POST['school'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$grad_year = $_POST['gradYear'];  //watch out for mysql injection here

$insert = "INSERT INTO hackers (name,email, school, grad-year)  VALUES('$name','$email','$school','$grad_year')";

$sql= "INSERT INTO mydatabase_name.hackers (name,email, school, grad-year) VALUES ('text', 'text', 'text', 'text')";
```

This should work. Look out for the proper quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the quotes. The following example is correct, adapt to yours.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mydatabase_name.hackers (name, email) 
                                     VALUES ('text', '$someVariable')";
```